# How can the regex be evaluated to different values

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I am running this code.

```
   console.log(/^[A-Za-z0-9_åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ]+$/.test("åååå"));
   console.log("testing " + nickName);
   console.log(/^[A-Za-z0-9_åäöæøÅÄÖÆØ]+$/.test(nickName));
```

result of log is

```
true   
åååå  
false
```

How can this happend? Is it something with the enconding?

I am using 

in my HTML. How is this possible?

"wwww" works. It only happends for the non English letters

edit: result from charcode

```
--- Nickname charcode---
charCodeAt(0)229 
charCodeAt(1)229 
charCodeAt(2)229 
charCodeAt(3)229
--Ã¥Ã¥Ã¥Ã¥ charcode---- 
charCodeAt(0)195 
charCodeAt(1)165 
charCodeAt(2)195 
charCodeAt(3)165
```

Comment: `console.log(nickName === 'åååå')`

Comment: @xdazz false. this is also false    console.log("testing 2" + nickName.toString() === 'åååå');

Comment: So that's the reason.

Comment: `var nickName = "åååå ";` is one way of producing that result.

Comment: And what does `console.log(nickName.indexOf('åååå'))` yield?

Comment: But still strange because åååå is what is getting logged. It is not a regex problem. I have no idea.

Comment: Try `console.log("testing :" + nickName + ":");` to make sure there are no spaces at the ends

Comment: @CBroe -1 is getting logged.

Comment: OK, that means additional whitespace is not the problem. But we have to little information to tell what else might be the problem.

Comment: @ArunPJohny There is no spaces. "wwww" works. It only happends for the non English letters.

Comment: What is `nickName.length`?

Comment: what is the character encoding for the page UTF-8/16

Comment: @ArunPJohny <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> so utf 8.

Comment: Changing to ISO-8859-1 did not help.

Comment: Well instead of changing things randomly and seeing if it fixes the issue by coincidence first diagnose the issue. What is `nickName.length`?

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith. nickName.length === 4. I dont think. I am doing this randomly. We have been testing for extra spaces and it only happends with letters like åæø so my guess is that it has something to do with the utf-8 or similar?

Comment: And if you use `charCodeAt` and compare the characters in both strings?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the soultion was to save my document with enconding Western-ISO-8859-1. Thats solved the problem. Thank you.